# Account Level view from Transaction Level Data

Tags: transactions, sas, large-data

So my question is regarding a peculiar problem i am facing regarding one of the areas i have to work in as part of my current job.

The domain is credit card transactions. So it's unique at a transaction level. But one person could be performing multiple transactions. Now obviously each transaction will not be identical.

So i have this basic characteristic dataset which i can manage easily. From this dataset, i want to assess Customer Level performance, across segments, which should be easily accessible without having to run my code for different combination of variables. Basically, what i'm aiming at is reaching at a customer level view, that doesn't cause any loss of information in terms of account, and i can still view the performance at a customer level, across segments.

Have any of you done a similar analysis? Or do you have any bright ideas as to how i should do this? I dont know how lucid this explanation is, but let me know if you need further explanation. Thanks for your help!

Comment: you need to be more concrete.  What do you have, what do you want, what have you tried......

Comment: Okay, So I have Transaction ID's. Which are unique. Against Each Transaction ID will be the Account ID. This will be repeated. Each transaction will be defined by a set of category variables. Say i have variables A,B,C,D for each transaction. And i have to give a performance analysis  of each combination of these variables. The Account ID's will be unique in each combination.

Say the problem is i have to summarize my performance at A,B level; and A,B and C level. 

I want to look at both views in a single csv. Currently all i think of is a proc summary and toggling the _TYPE_ variable.

Comment: If you want help make it easy for people to help you.  Post a small sample of you database with what you have and then try to post a small mock up of what you would like

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I3wqXiASYGQBElrZg-Tj4zpsDceVfQjJ_cPUxGaAx2E/edit?usp=sharing

Maybe this will help?

Comment: well that's better but what you show doesn't seem to make sense. a only has e and f and b only has g.  also b has multiple records so the sum would be far greater then $300.  Either explain in more detail what you are trying to do or post an example of  consistent datasets

Comment: Well, the idea is that in variable1=b segment, there are 5 transactions in all, but only 2 distinct customer ids. Its those two customers that i want to do a performance analysis on.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have data on 30 transactions that came from 10 customers (three transactions each).  In a relational database (and often it's a good idea in SAS as well), you would typically have a transaction table (with columns transactionID, customerID, transactionDate, transactionAmount) and a customer table (with columns customerID, customerName, customerSegment, etc).  That's part of database normalization. You separate the transaction-level data from the customer-level data.

If you're a fan of PROC SQL, that setup will work well for you in SAS.  If you want to analyze transactions for a certain customerSegment you just join the tables (or subquery or whatever).

The other option in SAS would be to merge the two tables by customerID, creating a data set that has one record per transaction, and has some variables that are attributes of a transaction, and other variables that are attributes of a customer.  So might look like:

```
custID  transID  transDate  transAmount  customerSegment  customerDOB
1       1        1/1/2015   100          A                1/1/1990
1       2        1/2/2015   50           A                1/1/1990
1       3        1/3/2015   75           A                1/1/1990
2       4        1/1/2015   10           B                12/12/1950
2       5        1/2/2015   5            B                12/12/1950
2       6        1/3/2015   75           B                12/12/1950
```

That is less efficient storage (and less normalized), because the values of the customer attributes are repeated for every transaction from the same customer.  But it can make life easier when you want to analyze transaction data by a customer attribute.

For more on this, google database normalization.  Toby Dunn has some nice papers on normalization in SAS, e.g. http://analytics.ncsu.edu/sesug/2007/TU03.pdf